# License code entered, but I get a warning when editing users

Tags: laravel-backpack

Hi everyone I am experiencing a problem with my Backpack license, I bought the license for a single project, and I have inserted the license into my .Env file as described in the documentation:
BACKPACK_LICENSE=XXXX-YYY-ZZZZ-XXXX-YYY-ZZZZ.
And set APP_ENV=production.
The system seems to recognise the licence correctly (no yellow warning is shown when logging in), however when I try to edit my users, the yellow warning appears with the words: "User editing is disabled in the demo version".
What's wrong?
I should point out that I have not activated the cache, but as a test I have also run the command as suggested: php artisan config:clear, but I still get this warning.
Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to ask this question of the developer/seller of the software, not stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've created your project starting from [the Backpack demo](https://demo.backpackforlaravel.com/admin/login). That's just an example Laravel + Backpack installation, to show off its features, it should *not* be used for real-life projects. Notice the [demo docs page](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/demo) says:

> **Don't use this demo to start your real projects.** Please use the [recommended installation procedure](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/installation). You don't want all the bogus entities we've created. You don't want all the packages we've used. And you definitely don't want the default admin user. Start from scratch.

I recommend you [create a new Laravel project](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x), then [install Backpack](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/installation) on top of it, then copy-paste your custom code in that new project. That will not only fix the inability to edit things, but many *other* problems like the ones listed in the quote above.